# Feature not activating after sharepoint 2007 upgrade to sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, feature-activation, features

After the 2007 to 2010 SharePoint upgrade i have taken notice that when i try to activate a feature under the site collection admin for a root site page and also with manage site features i keep on getting an error page as mentioned below.

```
<configuration>
         <system.web>
           <custom Errors mode="Off"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

I am confused as to why this problem would is occurring.

Comment: do you know what this custom feature contains?

Comment: It happens for all the features even the ones that are activated, when i try to deactivate they throw a custom error also

Comment: see my response.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you don't have enough permissions to activate custom features. I would recommend you opening SharePoint Management Shell (run it as an administrator) and run the following powershell to activate features:

```
Get-SPWebApplication nameofwebapplication| Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | % {Enable-SPFeature "nameoffeature" -Url $_.Url}
```

One more thing you can enable the custom error messages for layouts pages by changing the web.config in the following folder.

> C:\Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\template\layouts

web.config change:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Follow this [blog](http://falakmahmood.blogspot.se/2011/09/how-to-enable-full-errors-for.html) for more details:

Comment: Permission should not be a issue because i have the farm admin account and also the webapp admin account also.

Comment: did you the try the powershell as mentioned above?

Comment: I tried the powershell cmd and it still didnt activate it was complaining about a duplicate content type name "resource" was found

Comment: could you paste the complete error message?

Answer (score 0):

What is that feature supposed to do? You can try activating the feature again and check the log files at (14\Logs) to get the actual error message. Or you could turn on custom errors in web.config to get the actual message (but if this is already in prod, I would not do it this way).
Check [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/02/modifications-to-web-config-for-debugging-sharepoint-components.aspx) on how to turn on errors in web.config.